# Writing the scalar product using a determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ be symmetrical and positive definite. Does the following statement hold true for $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$?

$$\det(x^TAx) = \det(x^TxA)$$

And if so, how can it be proven? (Or disproven?)

Comment: It in general does not hold: take a unit vector $x$ to be an eigenvector of $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$, LHS=$\lambda$ but RHS=$\prod\lambda_i$, the product of all eigenvalues.

Comment: How can you multiply $x$ and $A$ as in $xA$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not true.  Take $x = \pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $A = \pmatrix{2&0\\0&2}$, for example.

Comment: Thanks, a friend of mine told me the statement was true, so I was looking for a way to prove it, instead of a nice counterexample like this :)